# How to avoid default value once after submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I set some default value for the number of textbox in the  `$(document).ready`. Whenever i reload the application or start the application this part is working fine. Once I change the default value from the textbox and submit after that the default value which i already set in the `$(document).ready` that appears. But I want the value which i changed from he textbox that will retain.

**JS file**

```js
         $(document).ready(function () {
                $('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function (e) {
                    if (e.key === "Enter") {
                        var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
                        focusable = form.find('input,select').filter(':visible:not([readonly]):enabled');
                        //:visible:not([readonly]):enabled
                        // focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
                        next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1);
                        if (next.length) {
                            next.focus();
                        } else {
                            form.submit();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    
                //default value
                $('#txtPercentofTier1').val(95).change();
                $('#txtPercentofTier2').val(0).change();
    
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblPercent" style="text-align:center">
        <thead>
            <tr style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center">
                <td style="width: 5%;" data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></td>
                <td>  </td>
                <td>IN Tier 1</td>
                <td >IN Tier 2</td>
                <td>OON</td>
                <td style="width: 8%">Not Covered</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                    <strong>% of service in plan Tier</strong>

                </td>
               
                 <td><asp:TextBox id="txtPercentofTier1" CssClass="TxtBox12"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span147" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentofTier2" CssClass="TxtBox12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span148" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
           
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtOON" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span149" runat="server" class="pers">%</span></td>
           
                <td>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is the submit button

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
    <div style="float: right; padding-right: 25px;">
      
        <asp:Button ID="SubBtn" CssClass="Planbtndis" runat="server"  Text="Submit" OnClick="SubBtn_Click" Enabled="False" />

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Did you store the value to DB or static value?

Comment: no. this is static value

Comment: Then you need to store in cookie

Comment: So to understand this correctly. You want to somehow store the changed value in your textbox so that if the application is reloaded, the value persists? If that's the case, you could use localstorage (client side), sessions (server side). However, the only way to keep the value indefinitely, is to store it into a database.

Comment: its not storing in the database either

Answer (score 0):

i found a good solution and it is working fine for me.

function invokeMeMaster() {

```
            var chkPostBack = '<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>';

            if (chkPostBack == 'false') {

                //default value
                $('#txtPercentofTier1').val(95).change();
                $('#txtPercentofTier2').val(0).change();

                //default value for Rx
                $('.txtRxTier1').val(0).change();
                $('.txtRxTier2').val(0).change();
                $('.txtOonRx').val(0).change();

            }
        }
        window.onload = function () { invokeMeMaster(); };
```